# Syscall to delay execution of a signal handler?

Tags: linux, c, signals

Is there a function or syscall with wich we can delay execution of a signal handler. Meaning that the signal handler will not be executed at the delivery of the signal, but after some other code being executed first ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `sigprocmask()` with the set of signals you wish to mask, or in a thread use `pthread_sigmask()`. See `man 7 signal` and the man page on each of the functions.